# How to migrate from Django Mezzanine to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, migration, mezzanine

I see a lot of posts and articles about migrating fron Wordpress to Django Mezzanine but I need to migrate the other way. Move content from Mezzanine and into Wordpress. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I had to get help to convert the content. As far as I know there are no tools that can automate this.

Comment: Im also looking for this.